# Mathbb in classicthesis and kpfonts

Tags: classicthesis, kpfonts

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
$\mathbb U$
\end{document}
```

is not giving me the `$\mathbb U$` of `amssymb`. Anything else is ok.

What should I do?

EDIT: sorry, I forgot the most important: \usepackage{amssymb}

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I can see the math blackboard character. What version do you use?

Comment: I get a kpfonts bb U as well

Comment: I realised it was a problem with amssymb.

Comment: With `kpfonts` you do not need `amssymb`, if both loaded, make use `kpfonts` is loaded **last**, as they define the same symbols and the last one loaded wins

Comment: I just prefer the look of \mathbb U with amssymb. And \usepackage{kpfonts} \usepackage{amssymb} works! It is just when I had classicthesis on top, that it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

Don't load `amssymb`. Just redeclare `\mathbb` at the right time:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{kpfonts}

\AtBeginDocument{\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}}

\begin{document}
$\mathbb{A}\mathbb{B}\mathbb{U}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly!